# Mapbox GL JS change marker image programmatically?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox GL JS to display a lot of pins on a map with custom marker image:

```
map.on('load', function () {
  map.loadImage("/path/to/pin1.png", function(error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage("custom-marker", image);
  });

  map.addLayer({
      id: "unclustered-point",
      source: "geolocations",
      filter: ["!", ["has", "point_count"]],
      type: "symbol",
      layout: {
          "icon-image": "custom-marker",
          "icon-allow-overlap": true,
          "icon-anchor": "bottom",
          "icon-size": 0.5
      }
  });

  //...

});
```

Is there any way to change a single marker image programmatically (e.g. the clicked marker)?

Comment: Lookup setFeatureState in the API docs, and feature-state in the style spec.

Comment: Already tried that, it throws an error: `"feature-state" data expressions are not supported with layout properties.`

Comment: Oh yes you're right sorry. In that case see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two layers, a "clicked" layer and an "unclicked" layer, then set the filter ([setFilter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter)) such that each layer filters only the clicked or unclicked features.

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 3 to 5***

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
               
        var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "marker")
        var annotationImageEnd = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "end")
            if annotationImage == nil {
               annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "trip_location"), reuseIdentifier: "marker")
                return annotationImage
            }else{
                annotationImageEnd = MGLAnnotationImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_end_marker"), reuseIdentifier: "end")
                return annotationImageEnd
            }
    }
```